# A particular section of data is being added twice in R

Tags: r

I use this particular code to add my data to R:

```
mydata <- read.table("c:/Eric.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=TRUE, quote= ",")
```

Then when i bring it up using " mydata ", it essential adds 154 people (which are found in row 186-340) , above my data, and then i get my actual headers (row 155) and how the data as it is supposed to be arranged. Is there anyway to change/add to my command to correct this?

Comment: your `quote=","` option is incorrect,remove it and let us know the output

Comment: taking out the quote="," resulted in this:
Warning messages:
1: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
2: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a CSV you are reading, consider using `read.csv()` function instead.

Comment: So i changed table to read.csv(): mydata <- read.csv("c:/Eric.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=TRUE, quote= ",")

and it loaded the data exactly as with read.table()

I will add that when i cut the data in half and retried it with my old code, it did not have the same problem, and the data was setup as it was supposed to be.

Comment: Going to facepalm myself right now because that worked perfectly. I did not try the read.csv before, but read.table did not work i know that when i first tried it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great! Hope you can accept the answer so we don't have too many unanswered questions lying around in the forum.